# How to prove the following Dirichlet-series/geometric-series idenity, step by step process?

Tags: geometric-series, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

$$\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(hs)} =\prod_p\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{p^{hs}}}{1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}}\right) =\prod_p\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}+\cdots +\frac{1}{p^{(h-1)s}}\right)=\sum_{n\in S_h}\frac{1}{n^s}$$

What is the step by step process proof of this series identity?

Hs is for h-free numbers, where in by definition it is positive integer n is square-free if and only if its prime factorization has no factors with
an exponent larger than one

I am stuck here:

$$\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(hs)}=\prod_p\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^{hs}}}\right)}
=\prod_p\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{p^{hs}}}{1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}}\right)$$

Would it be possible to come up with this?

$$\frac{1-\frac{1}{p^{hs}}}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}=\frac{\left(\frac{p^{hs}-1}{p^{hs}}\right)}{\left(\frac{p^s-1}{p^s}\right)}=\frac{p^s(p^{hs}-1)}{p^{hs}(p^s-1)}$$

Correct me if I'm wrong.

my question is that, how it leads to reimann zeta function?

Comment: The next steps comes from the formula for a finite geometric series:

$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Try this with $x = 1/p^s$ and $n=h-1$.

Comment: I have made various improvements to your question in an edit. Do make sure I haven't messed anything up.$\tag*{}$Please, in the future, do not use images to show your math; rather, you should typeset your math using MathJax. Also, please pick relevant tags, rather than picking random irrelevant tags. Relevant experts may not find your question if you don't use proper tags.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to tell us what $S_h$ means.

Comment: may i ask, how it leads to reimann zeta function?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need this formula:

For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$1-x^n = (1-x)(1+x+...+x^{n-1})$$

Which you can prove by induction. It follows that for all $x\not = 1$,
$$ \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} = 1+x+...+x^{n-1}$$
Now just plug in $x=\frac{1}{p^s}$.

Comment: thanks, may i know how it leads to reimann zeta functin?

Comment: @SuanSuan That's a beautiful, but not trivial idea. Look up Euler product formula, see e.g. this wiki cite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function